# For which $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$ is $\frac{1}{x^\alpha (\log(x))^\beta} \in L^p((1,\infty)$ where $1\leq p \leq \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I'm having a really hard time finding a starting point here. I think that it won't work for any $\alpha, \beta >0$ but I am not even sure about that.

Comment: Maybe try a substitution $u = \log(x)$?

Answer (score 1):

You have to study the integral
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{x^{p\alpha}(\log x)^{p\beta}}.
$$
At $x=1$, $\log x\sim x-1$. This will give you an integrability condition on $\beta$. At $x=\infty$, the dominant term is $x^{-p\alpha}$, and you get an integrability condition on $\alpha$.